# libreoffice calc - compute range based on boolean values

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice, libreoffice, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

Let's say I have a range

```
 OFFSET($AA:$AA,start_,0,stop_-start_,1)~OFFSET($BD:$BD,start_,0,stop_-start_,1)~OFFSET($CG:$CG,start_,0,stop_-start_,1)
```

And let's say I have three boolean fields named `valid1, valid2, valid3`.

How do I change the range formula s.t.  `OFFSET($AA:$AA,start_,0,stop_-start_,1)` only gets in cluded when `valid1` is true, `OFFSET($BD:$BD,start_,0,stop_-start_,1)` only when `valid2` is true and `OFFSET($CG:$CG,start_,0,stop_-start_,1)` only when `valid3` is true?

I.e. when, for example, `(valid1,valid2,valid3)==(1,0,1)`, the range should be reduced to `OFFSET($AA:$AA,start_,0,stop_-start_,1)~OFFSET($CG:$CG,start_,0,stop_-start_,1)`

Comment: What is the range being used for -- as an argument to a function perhaps?

Comment: @JimK as an argument to multiple, actually. Each subrange corresponds to an independent measurement.

Comment: What does "multiple" mean -- arguments to several different functions?  Please give a [verifiable, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of how this could be used.  Also have you tried using [IF](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Logical_Functions#IF)?